# Image of a closed point is closed when underlying ring is a finite type $K$-algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $\varphi:A\rightarrow A'$ be a morphism of algebras over a field $K$ and consider the associated map of spectra $\varphi^*:\operatorname{Spec}A'\rightarrow\operatorname{Spec}A$. I want to understand why the image of any closed point $x\in\operatorname{Spec}A'$ is closed in $\operatorname{Spec}A$ under the assumption that $A'$ is finite type over $K$. In particular, I'm having trouble seeing where the condition of finite type is to be used.

So let $P$ represent the prime ideal corresponding to $x$. Since $P$ is closed, we have $\overline{P}=V(P)=\{P\}$. What we want to show is that $\varphi^*(P)=V(\varphi^*(P))$. I'm not sure where to go from here. Any suggestions?

Comment: That’s wrong. Take $A’$ as the fraction field of $A=K[x]$. The condition is that $A’$ is of finite type over $K$.

Comment: @Mindlack That was a typo. Updated.

Comment: Hint: what can you say about the residue field of any closed point of the spectrum of $A’$? About the residue field of its image in the spectrum of $A$?

Answer (score 3):

Consider a maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}$ of $A'$, its preimage $\mathfrak{p}$ in $A$ and then look at $A/\mathfrak{p} \to A'/\mathfrak{m}$. Then you see that the claim is equivalent to the following:

> Let $ A \hookrightarrow A'$ be an injective homomorphism of $K$-algebras, where $A'$ is a field and a finitely generated $K$-algebra. Then $A$ is a field as well.

Notice that it is clearly necessary to assume some finiteness condition on $A'$ here, otherwise just consider the embedding of any domain into its field of fractions.

We need to use [Zariski's Lemma](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Zariski%27s_Lemma) (see the link for the proof), which implies that $A'$ is actually a finite-dimensional vector space over $K$. It follows that $A$ is a finite-dimensional vector space over $K$ as well. But since $A$ is a domain, $A$ must be a field (the left multiplication with a non-zero element is injective and therefore bijective).

Answer (score 0):

Lemma 2.2.3. Let $F$ be a field and $R$ an integral domain that is a finite-dimensional $F$-vector space. Then $R$ is a field.

Proof: Let $0\neq x\in R$ and let $\phi: F[t]\rightarrow k\{1,x,x^2,..,\}$
be the map defined by $\phi(t):=x$. Since $R$ is a ring it follows $\phi$ is a ring homomorphism, and since $dim_F(R) < \infty$ it follows there is an integer $n$ with $x^{n+1}\in F\{1,x,x^2,..,x^n\}$. Hence the map $\phi$ is a surjective map of $F$-algebras with $ker(\phi)=(p(t))$, where $p(t)$ is a non-zero polynomial. Since $R$ is an integral domain and $Im(\phi) \subseteq R$ is a sub ring it follows $F[t]/(p(t))$ is an integral domain, hence $p(t)$ is an irreducible polynomial. Since $p(t) \neq 0$ it follows $(p(t)) \subseteq F[t]$ is a maximal ideal, hence $Im(\phi)\subseteq R$ is a field containing $x$. It follows there is an element $0\neq y\in Im(\phi)$ with $xy=yx=1$ and it follows $R$ is a field. QED

**Answer:** In your case if $\mathfrak{m} \subseteq A'$ is a maximal ideal with $\mathfrak{m}\cap A:=\mathfrak{p}  \subseteq A$ you get an inclusion

$$ A/\mathfrak{p} \subseteq A'/\mathfrak{m}$$

and it follows $A/\mathfrak{p}$ is a field since $A'/\mathfrak{m}$ is a finite extension of $K$ by Prop. 7.9 in Atiyah-Macdonald.

Comment: The Lemma has a one-line proof (the left multiplication with a non-zero element is injective and therefore bijective). The main bulk of the proof is what you call the Nullstellensatz.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg - yes you are correct - I was referring to Prop 7.9 in AM.